# How to disable text field of desktop application which has no Id and Name

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using winiumDriver for desktop application. I want to disable textfield once value filled in the text field.

```
//open desktop application

WiniumDriver driver = null;

DesktopOptions option = new DesktopOptions();

option.setApplicationPath("Desktop application path");

driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);

WebElement window = driver.findElementByClassName("Qt5QWindowIcon");

List<WebElement> list = window.findElements(By.className(""));

//Send values to fields

list.get(10).sendKeys("USERNAME");

//javaScript code to disable

JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String todisable = "document.getElementsByName('')[10].setAttribute('disabled', '');";
javascript.executeScript(todisable);
```

//getting this eception

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown script command ' document.getElementsByClassName('')[10].setAttribute('disabled', '');'. See https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki/Command-Execute-Script for supported commands. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JL5UPRJ', ip: '192.168.0.112', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver

Comment: Provide more code.

Comment: Actually i'm new to selenium and winiumdriver. Help me out. I tried JavascriptExecutor  but i'm getting unknown script command exception.

Comment: Post the errors, in the question.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: @Ayoub_B sorry i dont have. its client desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop applications don't use JavaScript. Winium's implementation for executeScript specifically support few proprietary commands as described in the link in the error message, instead of actually executing JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other way to disable text field?

Comment: Not that I know of. May I ask why do you need to do that? Selenium (and Winium for that matter) are mainly intended for testing or for automating user actions. As the user can't disable an element manually, neither do Selenium and Winium.

Comment: I have two fields for my desktop application(Username and password). while entering password through sendkeys, if i click on username field through mouse at the same time, the password is displaying in username field so i want to avoid that by disabling username field. is there any other solution to do that?

Comment: UI automation on desktop (at least on Windows) uses the actual mouse pointer and keyboard focus of the OS. This means that you should not touch the mouse and keyboard while the test is running! If it takes too long and you don't want it to block you from working on the same time, you must use another machine or VM for that.